# Why the difference in query time for these two queries?

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.7, query-performance

I have a MySQL 5.7 database with a large table that has about 70,000,000 rows. There are 4 columns: `Id`, `Time`, `Value`, `Monitor_Id`. `Id` is the primary key, `Time` is indexed and `Monitor_Id` is a foreign key. `Value` is a `varchar(256)`.

I am doing two different queries:

```
SELECT * FROM monitorsamples where Time > '2019-06-28' and Monitor_Id = 19 order by Time desc;

SELECT * FROM monitorsamples where Time > '2019-06-28' and Monitor_Id >= 19 and Monitor_Id <= 35 order by Time desc;
```

The first query returns about 10,500 rows. The second query returns the cap of 50,000 rows. The first query takes about 10 seconds to complete and the second one takes less than 1/10 of a second. I am trying to understand why the more restrictive query takes longer?

This makes no sense to me. Anyone have an explanation for this?

UPDATE:

Here is the DDL for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `monitorsamples` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Value` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Monitor_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id` (`Id`),
  KEY `Monitor_Id` (`Monitor_Id`),
  KEY `Time` (`Time`),
  CONSTRAINT `MonitorSample_Monitor` FOREIGN KEY (`Monitor_Id`) REFERENCES `monitors` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Hope this provides some insight into the problem. I think there must be some fundamental DB magic happening under the hood that optimizes "x >= y and x <= z" versus the simpler "x = y". It is very counterintuitive.

UPDATE 2:

Here are the explains for both queries. The first one is the simpler query (first query from above).

```
select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'SIMPLE', 'monitorsamples', NULL, 'ref', 'Monitor_Id,Time', 'Monitor_Id', '4', 'const', '1040640', '5.60', 'Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort'
'SIMPLE', 'monitorsamples', NULL, 'range', 'Monitor_Id', 'Monitor_Id', '4', NULL, '9702114', '100.00', 'Using index condition; Using filesort'
```

I am not sure why the second query does not use `where`. And it looks like the second query uses few sorting and selection mechanisms and still executes faster.

UPDATE 3:

I am adding the explains in JSON format for each query to provide more detail.

Query 1:

```
{
    "query_block" : {
        "cost_info" : {
            "query_cost" : "773972.00"
        },
        "ordering_operation" : {
            "table" : {
                "access_type" : "ref",
                "attached_condition" : "(`monitorsamples`.`Time` > '2019-06-28')",
                "cost_info" : {
                    "data_read_per_join" : "53M",
                    "eval_cost" : "14293.85",
                    "prefix_cost" : "773972.00",
                    "read_cost" : "576000.00"
                },
                "filtered" : "7.22",
                "index_condition" : "(`monitorsamples`.`Monitor_Id` <=> 19)",
                "key" : "Monitor_Id",
                "key_length" : "4",
                "possible_keys" : [
                    "Monitor_Id",
                    "Time"
                ],
                "ref" : [
                    "const"
                ],
                "rows_examined_per_scan" : 989860,
                "rows_produced_per_join" : 71469,
                "table_name" : "monitorsamples",
                "used_columns" : [
                    "Id",
                    "Time",
                    "Value",
                    "Monitor_Id"
                ],
                "used_key_parts" : [
                    "Monitor_Id"
                ]
            },
            "using_filesort" : true
        },
        "select_id" : 1
    }
}
```

Query 2:

```
{
    "query_block" : {
        "cost_info" : {
            "query_cost" : "7243060.61"
        },
        "ordering_operation" : {
            "table" : {
                "access_type" : "range",
                "attached_condition" : "((`monitorsamples`.`Monitor_Id` >= 19) and (`monitorsamples`.`Monitor_Id` <= 35))",
                "cost_info" : {
                    "data_read_per_join" : "804M",
                    "eval_cost" : "215254.77",
                    "prefix_cost" : "7243060.61",
                    "read_cost" : "7027805.84"
                },
                "filtered" : "20.80",
                "index_condition" : "(`monitorsamples`.`Time` > '2019-06-28')",
                "key" : "Time",
                "key_length" : "5",
                "possible_keys" : [
                    "Monitor_Id",
                    "Time"
                ],
                "rows_examined_per_scan" : 5173614,
                "rows_produced_per_join" : 1076273,
                "table_name" : "monitorsamples",
                "used_columns" : [
                    "Id",
                    "Time",
                    "Value",
                    "Monitor_Id"
                ],
                "used_key_parts" : [
                    "Time"
                ]
            },
            "using_filesort" : false
        },
        "select_id" : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "cap of 50,000 rows", but I don't see `LIMIT 50000`.

Comment: It is the built-in GUI limit for Workbench. I have it set to 50K.

Comment: Add an index on `(time, monitor_id)` and compare again both queries. Then delete that index, add one at `(monitor_id, time)` and compare again both queries.  There is no magic.

Comment: Note that the faster one is "Using filesort"!  (It is faster because it touches a lot fewer rows, thereby more than compensating for the 'filesort'.)

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key, so the `UNIQUE(id)` is redundant and should be dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` !

Do you have `INDEX(Monitor_Id, Time)`?  It is the optimal index for the first query.  Meanwhile, there is no 'perfect' index for the second query.  I would *guess* that `INDEX(Time, Monitor_id)` would be best.

What will you do with a resultset of 50K rows?  That will choke any web site.  If you are processing the data, consider doing some or all of the processing in SQL.  It is likely to be much faster than shoveling 50K rows to the client.

Is some combination of columns (other than `id`) unique?  If so, I can probably speed them up even more.

[*Indexing Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: I don't want 50K rows. I just wonder why 50K rows performs better than the first query that returns 10K rows when they are essentially doing the same thing. More restrictive should perform better.

Comment: @Psyfun - I need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to explain the difference.

Comment: No worries. I updated the question to provide the information you were looking for. Hope this helps. Also, the goal for the query is to return the previous X days worth of data for generating a graph/chart.

Comment: @Psyfun - Sorry, but I need something else:  `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` -- for each of the selects.  I suspect it is using a different index.

Comment: I added the explains. Hope that sheds some light on why these queries are operating and performing differently.

Comment: @Psyfun -- Still puzzling.  Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for each query.  That will give more insight into how the Optimizer is executing the queries.  ('ref' vs 'range' refers to `MonitorId`; I can't explain the "Using where" difference.)

Comment: I added the extended explain in JSON format. It looks the index versus the "attached condition" are swapped for the queries. That must account for the different performances.

Comment: @Psyfun - Now try with the two suggested composite indexes.

Comment: I added the index for (Monitor_Id, Time) and that seems to have cleared up the problem. Both queries return very quickly now with the simpler one being slightly faster. Thanks so much for the help and suggestions. I would still like to know why MySQL made the choices it made based on how the query was structured, but in the end, it's the results that matter.